# How can I do an 'omitempty' in an UpdateOne stattement

Tags: mongodb, go

I receive some fields in the body, but I have this code:

```
    registro := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "nombre":          b.Nombre,
            "apellidos":       b.Apellidos,
            "fechaNacimiento": b.FechaNacimiento,
            "email":           b.Email,
            "password":        passwordEncriptada,
            "avatar":          b.Avatar,
            "banner":          b.Banner,
            "biografia":       b.Biografia,
            "domicilio":       b.Domicilio,
            "sitioWeb":        b.SitioWeb,
        },
    }

    objID, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(ID)
    filtro := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$eq": objID}}

    _, err := col.UpdateOne(ctx, filtro, registro)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
```

This results in all fields in the MongoDB document, but some of this fields are empty.

How can I do a `omitempty` during `UpdateOne()`?

Regards

Comment: Selectively add them to the `$set` object only if they are not empty?

Comment: Well, but "$set" is not a single String, where you can concatenate other strings... What is the best practice about ? thanks

Comment: Check out [type M](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M) in the docs.  You should be able to build that map ahead of time, and pass it to bson.M once you have the fields you want in it.

Comment: I'm cheking but I don't understand.. have you some example that allow me to understand how add in realtime fields to a initial Bson.M struct ? thanks

Comment: I have this registro := make(map[string]bson.M)
 if len(u.Nombre) > 0 {
  registro["nombre"] = u.Nombre
 }
but I have error because 'u.Nombre' is string, and registro is a primitive.M type.. what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do a omitempty during UpdateOne()?

You can just build a struct before passing into the update statement. The update statement will go through [bson.Marshal()](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#Marshal) before being passed through. For example if you have the following struct:

```
type Test struct {
    Banner string      `json:"banner" bson:"banner,omitempty"`
    Email  string      `json:"email" bson:"email,omitempty"`
    Avatar string      `json:"avatar" bson:"avatar,omitempty"`
    Age    int32       `json:"age" bson:"age,omitempty"`
}
```

You can just construct the struct for the update as below:

```
filter := bson.M{}
foo := Test{Banner:"updated", Avatar:"updated", Email:"", Age:0}
statement := bson.M{"$set": foo}
result, err := collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, statement)
```

After the update operation, the value of `Email` and `Age` field should not be updated.